# WillpopScope is misbehaving in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview

update: check this onwillpop method. and tell what changes can i do.

```
onWillPop: () async {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Xác nhận thoát"),
                content: Text("Bạn có chắc bạn muốn thoát?"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: Text("VÂNG"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: Text("KHÔNG"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
        return Future.value(true);
      },
```

Whenever i am a webpage, and browse site, the back button functionality doesn't works properly,
When i press back it opens willpopscope instead it should do Back (just like web browsing)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WebViewController _controller;

    final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
        Completer<WebViewController>();
    return WillPopScope(
      child: netState
          ? Scaffold(
              body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: widget.homeURL,
                  zoomEnabled: false,
                  userAgent: 'random',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controllerCompleter.future
                        .then((value) => _controller = value);
                    _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
                    if (request.url.startsWith(widget.homeURL) ||
                        request.url.contains("https://test-payment.momo.vn/") ||
                        request.url.contains("https://payment.momo.vn/") ||
                        request.url.startsWith(
                            "momo://app?action=payWithAppToken&amount=") ||
                        request.url.contains("google.com") ||
                        request.url.contains("facebook.com")) {
                      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                    } else {
                      return _launchURL(request.url);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all extract `_controller` from the `build` method

```
WebViewController? _controller;
```

In the `onWillPop` callback of `WillPopScope` widget specify when you have to navigate back by **webview** or not

```
onWillPop: () async {
    final canGoBack = await _controller?.canGoBack() ?? false;
    if (canGoBack) {
      _controller?.goBack();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
```

An updated version of your `build` method

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final canGoBack = await _controller?.canGoBack() ?? false;
        if (canGoBack) {
          _controller?.goBack();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: ...
```

[image]

Comment: i am unable to change this it;s showing error.

Comment: please check my code again.

Comment: Just use cade that I shared before

Comment: sir, i did as you explained but the problem is still there?

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of flutter `WillPopScope` was [deprecated](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#migrating-from-willpopscope-to-popscope) and `PopScope`
should be used instead. Here's an example of how you should use it

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return PopScope(
       canPop: false,
       onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
          if (didPop) return;
          await _canPop();
         },
         child: ...
      )}
```

Function _canPop()

```
Future<void> _canPop() async {
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
    } else {
      navigator.pop();
    }
  }
```